# Error on sequelize.import: defineCall is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, npm, sequelize.js

The error I'm getting is this:

```
C:\Users\brend\project\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:392
      this.importCache[path] = defineCall(this, DataTypes);
                               ^
TypeError: defineCall is not a function
    at Sequelize.import (C:\Users\brend\project\server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:392:32)
    at fs.readdirSync.filter.forEach (C:\Users\brend\project\server\src\models\index.js:20:35)
```

I'm learning as I go with node, vue and a bunch of libraries, and I haven't been able to figure this out.

index.js is as following:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
    file !== 'index.js'
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname), file)
    db[model.name] = model
  })

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

And here is my User.js, which is the only model I have currently:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
  sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  })
```

And if necessary, my folder structure:

```
-src
--app.js
--routes.js

--config
----config.js

--controllers
----AuthenticationController.js

--models
----index.js
----User.js
```

There's also the thing that in my app.js `sequelize.sync()` is not defined, at least that's what my IDE indicates.

Answer (score 13):

I found this on github [sequelize github](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7934), replace

```
const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
```

with

```
var model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

It works for me with sequelize 6.3.0

Answer (score 13):

> sequelize.import has been deprecated in sequelize v6+. It was there
> till v5

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/upgrade-to-v6.html#sequelize
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html

#### Earlier `models/index.js` that works till sequelize `v5`:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
    file !== 'index.js'
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname), file) // error occurs here
    db[model.name] = model
  })

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

## Now sequelize v6+ onwards `sequelize.import` will not be available.

#### So make below changes in forEach part of `models/index.js`

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) =>
    file !== 'index.js'
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    //-----------------------THIS PART HERE-----------------------
    /**
     * Choose any one of the below definition for model variable 
     */
    // for individual model files having `export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {`    
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file)).default(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes); 
    // for individual model files having `module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {`    
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);

    db[model.name] = model;
    //----------------------------------------------------------
  })

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

Points to  note:

- if using `export default ...` in model  files & also babel -> we are using `require(...).default`
- as `require(...)` does not return a function and rather returns a object as : `{ default: [Function] }` and hence using property 'default' of it

Answer (score 2):

"sequelize.import" has been Deprecated. You should use "require" instead.

See *artfulbeest* solution above. It worked for me.

Further reading go here to the official docs (https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-definition.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of sequelize you are using. I had a persistent error when I used `sequelize@6.0.0-beta.6` and discovered that `import` was missing from the sequelize object/ client:

> npm uninstall sequelize

> npm install sequelize

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the solution on sequelize": "^6.3.4
> Replace

```
const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
```

With

```
const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

**models/index.js:**

```
...

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file) => {
        return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== "index.js");
    })
    .forEach((file) => {
        const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

    Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
            db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
    });
...
```

**models/user.js:** (I used in lowercase)

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    password: Sequelize.STRING
  })

  return User;
}
```

**Call model.user:**

```
const model = require('./models'); // Change path if is necesary
model.user.create({ ...
```

Comment: TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function