# AuthenticationController always throws error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have an issue with the Authenticati onController used with sequelize and sqlite
When I test the POST request using postman, it always gives status 400  with the response
{
error: 'Something is wrong'
}
[image]
This is the log

::1 - - [21/Jul/2020:15:40:33 +0000] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 400 30 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.26.1"

[image]
Here is the code of AuthenticationController

```js
const {User} = require('../models')
module.exports = {
    async register(req, res){
        try {   
            const user = await User.create(req.body)
            res.send(user.toJSON())
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.status(400).send({
                error: 'Something is wrong'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

User model code

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
sequelize.define('User', {
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING
})
```

models index code

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)
fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname)
    .filter((file)=>{
        file != 'index.js'
    })
    .forEach((file)=>{
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
          sequelize,
          Sequelize.DataTypes
        );
        // const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname,file))
        db[model.name] = model
    })
    db.sequelize = sequelize
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

routes code

```js
const AuthenticationController = require('./controllers/AuthenticationController');

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.post('/register',
     AuthenticationController.register)
}
```

Earlier, it was  throwing an error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"
But when I restarted the server, that was fixed. But I have no clues as to why the try block fails.

Anyone could  throw some light on this? Thank you

Comment: The register route returns a 400 response if any error occurs in the try block.  What is the `err` in the catch block?  That is the starting point for what issue is triggering the 400 response.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I modified the catch block by adding "console.log(error)" . This time, I am getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined". Please see the image added

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring at `User.create(req.body)` - the `User` variable is undefined.  The User variable comes from the models index file.  So why is db.User undefined in the model index file?  I haven't used sequelize much, so no obvious issue jumps out at me.  However, I'd guess it has something to do with the forEach block in the model index file or the user model file.

Comment: You're right! When I removed forEach block and defined db.User separately, it gave an error "TypeError: sequelize.import is not a function"

Comment: Found a similar thread here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080727/error-on-sequelize-import-definecall-is-not-a-function
But the fix with 'require' also didn't solve my issue

Comment: That sounds like progress to me.  I assume that the require logic in the forEach block is now working and the model is being defined.  The next thing to look for is why isn't the `model.name` key being set on db?  Without knowing what error message you are now getting, here is a guess - the user model module.exports function does not define a return value so the `model` variable in the models index code is always undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218319/discussion-between-rhythmo-and-crumkev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the revised code for /models/index.js

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.db.database,
  config.db.user,
  config.db.password,
  config.db.options
)
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
    //   .filter((file) => {
    //     file != "index.js";
    //   })
  .filter(
    (file) =>
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== "index.js" && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
  )
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    // const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname,file))
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
    db.sequelize = sequelize
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

The filter block was updated as shown in the revised, with the help of the link
https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/sequelize/Sequelize/import
The 2 things that were changed are

1. Replaced the 'sequelize.import' with 'require'
2. Updated the 'filter' block  as shown.

Here is the result:
[image]

Thanks to crumkev for the insight which led me find the answer.