# Setting Sequelize associations in Node - Postman throwing constraint errors

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postman

I am trying to set my Sequelize associations correctly so that all my "include" data is pulled when I make requests. I have seen the information in the docs relating to this however it is a bit hard to understand without seeing it in an app.

I previously had associations in however they never pulled the foreign key values and I only had "include all" in the API's. I now have more specific "include: ["articleType"] at the start of my data pulls. As I am working without migrations I am not sure if I am updating pgAdmin correctly (I am only putting foreign keys in for ones that I am able as making a foreign key out of a primary key is not allowed due to the unique constraint error).

Ideally I just want to get my backend API's to pull the foreign key values the most efficient way as I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I don't have migrations as this is just a project so this could be a cause if the information isn't being duplicated in Pgadmin.

**Firstly** in PGadmin how should I reflect the constraints that I have in my models? can these be done manually? I can't see the manyToMany, belongTo etc only the simple foreign key restraint to a primary key on another table.

**Secondly**, on my models below do I need keys declared on both related models? In PGadmin I am unable to declare a foreign key on a Primary key whereas it works fine from another table to a primary key.

Is there a way to manually add in SQL joins even with Sequelize so that the correct foreign key values are included in the JSON? I have previous experience with PHP / PHPmyAdmin and it was much easier with that. From what I can see my articles model is referencing the articleType model both on Pgadmin and my files in my backend and I am also referencing them in my controller API (which seems to be causing the error as the other API's work correctly without the "include" part in the method).

[image]

[image]

article model

```
    const article = sequelize.define("articles", {

            articleID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                allowNull: false
            },
            articleTitle: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            articleContent: {
                    type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            photos: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            },
            userID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            articleTypeID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            }},
            {
                timestamps: false
            }, {});
            article.associate = function(models) {
                article.hasMany(models.articleType, {
                    foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
                    as: "articleType_FK"});
                article.hasMany(models.userLogin, {
                    foreignKey: "userID",
                    as: "userLogin_FK"});
            }
    return article;
```

articleType model

```
    const articleType = sequelize.define("articleTypes", {

            articleTypeID: {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            articleType: {
                type: Sequelize.TEXT
            }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        },{});
        articleType.associate = function(models) {
            articleType.belongsTo(models.article, {
                foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
                as: "article",
            });
        }
    return articleType;
}
```

article controller

```
exports.articleList = (req, res) => {
    // article.findByPk(articleID, { include: ["articleType"] });
    article.findAll({
        **include: [{ model: articleType, as: 'fki_articleType_FK'},
                  { model: userLogin, as: 'fki_userID_FK'}]
    })**
        .then((article) => {
            const articleList = [];
```

**Update**

I had previously created a number of associations in my index.js file in the models folder however I now only have these in the actual model. Do these need to put in both?

[image]

Comment: You've aliased the relation to 'articleType_FK', try that in the include instead

Comment: I have changed it and I am getting a ""message Association with alias \"articleType_FK\" does not exist on articles".

Comment: Can you show how your models/index.js looks like? Issue might be that the association weren't initialized so Sequelize doesn't know what is the association between your models |||||| Also please add the latest error snapshot that you get now.

Comment: Also please remove the 's' from model name in all your sequelize.define ||||  `const articleType = sequelize.define("articleType", {`   & `const article = sequelize.define("article", {` |||||| I think after doing this change it is just gonna work fine

Comment: Do I need the associations in both my index file and model? Would I need to run the Sequelize sync true again so these are reflected in pgAdmin? I don't have migrations so these aren't being updated automatically.

Comment: No associations in model is enough and the way you have defined is also perfect. Index file just need to execute them. models/index.js file should look something like the updated file here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984731/8133717

Answer (score 1):

I probably think the issue is the model name that you provide to seuqelize and afterwards that you use in Association.

```js
 const article = sequelize.define("articles", {...
```

This results in a model named - `articles` accessible via `models.articles` for your associations.
Issue occurs here:

```js
articleType.associate = function (models) {
    articleType.belongsTo(models.article, { // models.article will be undefined
        foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
        as: "article",
    });

// This below should rather work
articleType.associate = function (models) {
    articleType.belongsTo(models.articles, { // models.articles exist as you told Sequelize to name it with that extra 's'
        foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
        as: "article",
    });
}
}
```

But better mention the name of model without `s` so that it never creates issues and confusion

So what will work?:

```js
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// models/article.js
const article = sequelize.define("article", {
  //attributes
}, {
  // options
});
article.associate = function (models) {
    article.hasMany(models.articleType, {
        foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
        as: "articleType_FK"
    });
  // other associations
}
return article;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// models/articleType.js
const articleType = sequelize.define("articleType", {
    // attributes
}, {
    // options
});
articleType.associate = function (models) {
    articleType.belongsTo(models.article, {
        foreignKey: "articleTypeID",
        as: "article",
    });
}
return articleType;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// controller
exports.articleList = (req, res) => {
    // article.findByPk(articleID, { include: ["articleType"] });
    article
        .findAll({
            include: [{
                model: articleType, as: 'articleType_FK',
            }, {
                model: userLogin, as: 'userID_FK',
            }],
        })
        .then((articles) => {
            console.log('articles', articles);
        })
}
```

Comment: I have went through and matched up all the foreign keys and duplicated them in my index.js file. It looks like I have made progress and the system seems to recognizing them however I am now getting empty arrays when there should be values. Where does this usually mean I am going wrong? the controller API?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, Hopefully your issue will resolve.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ArticleTypes = sequelize.define(
        'articleTypes',
        {
            uuid: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                unique: true
            }
            // Your article type schema ...
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
            schema: 'articleTypes'
        }
    );
    return ArticleTypes;
};
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Articles = sequelize.define(
        'articles',
        {
            uuid: {
                type: DataTypes.UUID,
                defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
                unique: true
            }
            // Your article schema ...
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
            schema: 'articles'
        }
    );
    Articles.associate = (models) => {
        Articles.belongsTo(models.ArticleTypes, {
            as: 'ArticleTypes',
            foreignKey: 'articleTypeID'
        });
    };
    return Articles;
};
```

create model like above. rest part is same as you used.